# how cloudflare cdn cert passes domain check?

Tags: https, security-certificate, cloudflare

How cloudflare-based site passes browser's domain check?
when I visit cloudflare based site, it provides a cert for cloudflare domains(like sni007.cloudflaressl.com) but browser does not shows any security warning.

i.e. let demo.example.com as cloudflare-based site.
then visit https://demo.example.com with browser. it browses with no warning, though it provided a cert issued to sni007.cloudflaressl.com, not [demo.example.com | *.example.com].

Answer (score 1):

If you want people to see something, provide true URLs not obfuscated one.

Also, you need to see far more inside the certificate, not just the CN but also in extensions the Subject Alternative Names. This is explained here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203041594-What-browsers-work-with-CloudFlare-s-SSL-certificates-  and here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204144518-SSL-FAQ